# Very Simple if else statements doesn't working. what im doing wrong?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to Java. I'm learning by myself without guide. Can anyone help me with this little piece of code? What am I doing wrong??

```
package Lessons;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lesson1
{
    public static void main (String []Args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int age;
        System.out.println("How old are you?");
        age = input.nextInt();
            if (age >= 20);
                System.out.print("You Passed!");
            else
                ( age <= 20)
                System.out.println("You Failed!");
    }
}
```

The issue is in else. I'm working on Eclipse and I don't get any help solution from it on what to do.

Comment: `if (age >= 20);` - remove `;` and also remove `( age <= 20)`

Comment: Recommendation: always use `{` and `}` to delimit the statements that you want to run after an `if` and after the matching `else`.  Otherwise, madness ensues.

Comment: Eclipse has a code-formatter. That will fix indentation and the bug becomes obvious. Use it.

Comment: @GhostCat how can you say "sure it works" for that which compileth not?

Comment: @DavidWallace Touche. But then: I hope you are really not encouraging to use ?: over if/else here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to add curly braces too see what if-else statements cover.

What you **need** however is to remove semicolon and remove boolean expression from else statement

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age;
    System.out.println("How old are you?");
    age = input.nextInt();
    // Added {} and removed ;
    if (age >= 20) {
        System.out.print("You Passed!");
    // Added curly brackets and removed boolean expression
    } else {
        System.out.println("You Failed!");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you have ";" after if. Why?

Also you shouldn't write "else (...)", at least "else if(...)"

So, the correct code, if I understand right what you want is:

```
package Lessons;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class lesson1 {
    public static void main(String[] Args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int age;

        System.out.println("How old are you?");

        age = input.nextInt();

        if (age >= 20) {
            System.out.print("You Passed!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You Failed!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i dont know why i put it them haha, like i said i started few weeks ago and i dont really know even the basics :) by the way it worked, it was what i want it. thanks